# Unable to make opportunity status bar readonly

Tags: odoo

I would like to mark the opportunity stages readonly. I've tried the following ways

**Method 1**

```
'stage_id': fields.many2one(
    'crm.case.stage',
    'Stage',
    track_visibility='onchange',
    domain="[
            '&', '&',
            ('fold', '=', False), ('section_ids', '=', section_id),
             '|',
            ('type', '=', type), ('type', '=', 'both')]",
    readonly=True
    ),
```

**Method 2**

```
<field
    name="stage_id"
    widget="statusbar"
    clickable="False"
    domain="[
            '&amp;', '|',
            ('case_default', '=', True), ('section_ids', '=', section_id),
            '|',
            ('type', '=', type), ('type', '=', 'both')
            ]"
    on_change="onchange_stage_id(stage_id)"
    />
```

Both the methods didn't work out. Kindly help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**#For .py#**

```
'state' : fields.selection([('draft','Draft'),('submit','Submit'),('reject','Reject'),('approve','Approve')],'State'),
```

**#For .xml#**

```
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,submit,reject,approve" statusbar_colors='{"r":"red"}' groups="<Add Group>" />
```